# Reload managed synonyms in Solr

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solr-schema, solr-search

I am using Solr 8.6.1, started in solrcloud mode.
The field type is

```
{
          "add-field-type" : {
              "name":"articleTitle",
              "positionIncrementGap":100,
              "multiValued":false,
              "class":"solr.TextField",
              "indexAnalyzer":{
                  "tokenizer":{ "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" },
                  "filters":[
                      { "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" },
                      { "class":"solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory", "managed":"english" },
                      { "class":"solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory", "managed":"english" },
                      { "class":"solr.FlattenGraphFilterFactory" },
                      { "class":"solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" }
                  ]
              },
              "queryAnalyzer":{
                  "tokenizer":{ "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" },
                  "filters":[
                      { "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" },
                      { "class":"solr.ManagedStopFilterFactory", "managed":"english" },
                      { "class":"solr.ManagedSynonymGraphFilterFactory", "managed":"english" },
                      { "class":"solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" }
                  ]
              }
          }
      }
```

After I add a document

```
{
  "id": 100,
  "articleTitle": "Best smartphone"
}
```

I update the synonyms list by API

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '["iphone", "smartphone"]' "http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/schema/analysis/synonyms/english"
```

and reload the collection by API

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=articles
```

However when I try to search the documents don't pop-up.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/articles/select?q=articleTitle:iphone
```

No result are returned. I expected that added document will be returned.

It works only if I first update the synonyms list and after that add the document into collection.

How to configure Solr to find the documents by synonyms if the synonyms are changed after documents are created?

Comment: If you depend on the synonyms being expanded index time, then only re-indexing the document will change the tokens stored for that field. You'll have to add proper examples of what doesn't work - i.e. what content you're indexing and how you're querying it - what you expect the result to be and what it actually is.

Comment: It will work for me if synonyms will be expanded at query time

Comment: Then you shouldn't have to re-add your document. Add proper examples about the issue - you can also use the "Analysis" page under Solr's admin to see exactly how your input text is being processed.

Comment: @MatsLindh I've updated the question with examples

Comment: The analysis page should show you what expansion is taking place with your query; you should be able to see if the `smartphone` token is included - the graph part might also play a role. I don't have an environment right here to test with, but that should give you a good hint on where to continue

Comment: If you are new to synonyms in Solr you might find this useful: https://library.brown.edu/DigitalTechnologies/using-synonyms-in-solr/